# Should a push profile contain the company certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having problems getting push notifications to work when using an ad-hoc build/distribution, though push is working when built with a development profile.

Looking at the push profile I can see that it lists certificates for some developers and for the adp agent. Should it additionally contain the company certificate?  i.e. the certificate that is named after the company and which is present in the ad-hoc distribution profile? If so how it is added.

Answer (score 2):

Be carefull with certificates. You have a certificate for development and distribution.It happen the same with the push notification certificates.

In the provisioning profile you have to make sure that the appID has a distribution certificate associated with it. Then you need to create a distribution provisioning certificate. Note that this will be different for development, ad hoc and app store distribution.

You also need to change the certificate that your APNS server is using. Finally, make sure that in xcode, your app is using the correct certificates when building your project and target.

Comment: I know how to add/update profiles within XCode, but how do you update the certificates in Xcode?